# Odd isDirectory behaviour

Tags: java, file, directory

I've looked around at similar questions on here but none of the answers I have attempted have proven useful. I am attempting to load a directory that exists on the web. When I navigate to the path that my program is generating, it is definitely a directory. However, when I attempt to use `isDirectory` on the file object representing the path, it doesn't work.

**Snippet where I Generate the file**

```
if (sport == null || sport.trim().length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    File dayDirectory = new File(aggregatorRootDirectory, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date));
    String sportDirectory = sport.replace(",", "");

    return new File(dayDirectory + "\\" + sportDirectory + "\\");
```

The path that this is generating is valid, and is definitely a directory. The directory is a website link, if that makes a huge difference?

**Snippet where I use the file**

```
 try {
        if (directory == null || !directory.getCanonicalFile().isDirectory() || 
            fileNamePattern == null || fileNamePattern.trim().length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

This attempt is throwing a `java.io.IOException` with the message:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The error is occuring in the `if statement`, when I attempt to call `getCanonicalFile()`.

When I remove the `getCanonicalFile()` method call, it resolves to `false` when I call `isDirectory`.

If I remove the check all together, `listFiles()` resolves to `null`, which is making me think there's something more to this.

Is there a common issue with `isDirectory` and web links, or is there a way to force a file object to intepret a path as a directory?

**Edit**

Below is the Scala code that performed the desired functionality. The following function grabbed the list of files from the online directory:

```
private def getFiles(directory: File, fileNamePattern: String): Seq[Elem] = {    

if(directory == null || ! directory.isDirectory
|| fileNamePattern == null || fileNamePattern.trim.length == 0) {
  return Nil
}  

val filesList = directory.listFiles( new FilenameFilter {
       override def accept(dir: File, name: String) = { name.matches(fileNamePattern) 
} } )

val sortedFilesList = filesList.sortBy(_.lastModified)

val feedsList = mutable.ListBuffer[Elem]() 

for(file <- sortedFilesList) {
  try {     
    feedsList += XML.loadFile(file) % new UnprefixedAttribute("original-filePath", file.getCanonicalPath, Null)
  }
  catch {
    case _ => // TODO log
  }
}   

feedsList
}
```

And this function created a new File object from said directory.

```
 private def getSportDirectory(sport: String, date: Date = new Date): File = {

if(sport == null || sport.trim.length == 0) {
  return null;
}

val dayDirectory = new File(aggregatorRootDirectory, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date))
val sportDirectory = sport.replace(",", "") // resolving sports like "HR,DG" to "HRDG". Not ideal but ...

new File(dayDirectory, sportDirectory)
}
```

Comment: *"The directory is a website link, if that makes a huge difference?"* - Yes.  What you web service exposes is not a directory, but a URL/resource.  It is NOT a directory in the sense of a directory on local drive.  It is exposed as a resource by the web server and you need to treat it like any other web resource, if exposed, it will be listed in HTML

Comment: If that's still a `java.io.File`, then I'm *very* surprised it worked.  If it's `scala.io.File` then I'd still want to know what's happening at the HTTP level...

Comment: Agreed. I think I'm going to do some more digging. All I know is that the scala program managed to achieve this functionality, and this appears to be the code that ran it (but because maven doesn't seem to want to download the scala plugin, I can't debug it). I'm going to try and get a working Scala IDE and give it another go. I will keep you posted. Thanks for the extra help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The directory is a website link, if that makes a huge difference?

Yes, it absolutely does. `File` is intended for *file systems* - not HTTP.

Basically, you shouldn't be using `File*` classes if you're trying to do things with web resources. Just because various applications (e.g. Windows Explorer) try to hide the differences between the two doesn't mean you can always do so in code.

For example, I don't believe that there *is* a generic HTTP equivalent of "list files" for a directory. You request a specific resource - and that *may* return a directory listing, but it could equally give the default page for a directory.

Comment: Is there an object I can use in a similar way for a web resource?

Comment: @Chris: Not to list files, no - I've just edited my answer to mention that. There are various HTTP client libraries for other web operations though, with the Apache one being the most common.

Comment: @Chris Not really.  The only choice you have is a URL, but you will need to know that the web server is exposing that directory and the path to it from the context of the web server.  Then you will most likely need to process the result as HTML

Comment: Okay. Thanks Jon. I'll mark this as correct anyhow, and I'll look into the Apache library. Thankyou!

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi Jon. I've been looking for a while, and I can't find an Apache library that will allow me to perform similar functionality. if it helps, I'm converting this app over from Scala, and the scala app did this operation fine, so it's definitely possible. I'm just somewhat confused about how to implement it in Java?

Comment: @Chris: The Scala version managed to get directory listings for arbitrary "directory" URLs? I'd be very surprised if that were the case. Perhaps you should edit the Scala code into your question...